# CSS Grid inside Grid should not depend on row height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following React component that has a three column grid.

Inside each column I have another grid with 2 columns per row.

[image]

```
const dialogContentStyle = (theme: Theme) =>
    css({
      display: 'grid',
      padding: `12px 24px`,
      gridTemplateAreas: `
        "about statement regulations"
      `,
      gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr 1fr',
      gridTemplateRows: 'auto',
      gridRowGap: theme['one-spacer-16'],
      gridColumnGap: '5%',
    });

  const dialogAboutStyles = (theme: Theme) =>
    css({
      gridArea: 'about',
      display: 'grid',
      // alignItems: 'start',
      gap: theme['one-spacer-16'],
      gridTemplateColumns: '0.6fr 1fr',
    });

  const dialogStatementStyles = (theme: Theme) =>
    css({
      gridArea: 'statement',
      display: 'grid',
      // alignItems: 'start',
      gap: theme['one-spacer-16'],
      gridTemplateColumns: '0.5fr 1fr',
    });
```

The first Grid that has the three columns is using `dialogContentStyle`.

Inside `dialogContentStyle` I am using `dialogAboutStyles` and `dialogStatementStyles` for each column (last one is missing).

```
    <div css={dialogContentStyle}>
        <div css={dialogAboutStyles} style={{ gridRow: 1 }}>
          <OwcTypography variant="subtitle2" css={{ gridColumn: 1 }}>
            Software Version
          </OwcTypography>
          <OwcTypography variant="body1" css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>
            2.6.0
          </OwcTypography>
        </div>
        <div css={dialogAboutStyles} style={{ gridRow: 2 }}>
          <UdiSvg />
          <OwcTypography variant="body1" css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>
            (01)GTIN(8012)V.I
          </OwcTypography>
        </div>
        <div css={dialogAboutStyles} style={{ gridRow: 3 }}>
          <OwcTypography variant="subtitle2" css={{ gridColumn: 1 }}>
            Copyright
          </OwcTypography>
          <OwcTypography variant="body1" css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>
            Copyright © 2023 . All rights reserved. fsadfsdafass fsadfsfsf is licenced for use
            between . and the licensee, and only users authorized there under are permitted to
            access and use the software. Unauthorized use and distribution may result in civil and
            criminal penalties.
          </OwcTypography>
        </div>
        <div css={dialogAboutStyles} style={{ gridRow: 4 }}>
          <OwcTypography variant="subtitle2" css={{ gridColumn: 1 }}>
            Trademarks
          </OwcTypography>
          <OwcTypography variant="body1" css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>
            fsafdsaf is a trademark of fdsfasfs. <br /> <br />
            Other product names and trademarks are the property of their respective owners.
          </OwcTypography>
        </div>
        <div css={dialogAboutStyles} style={{ gridRow: 5 }}>
          <OwcTypography variant="subtitle2" css={{ gridColumn: 1 }}>
            Open Source and Commercial Software
          </OwcTypography>
          <OwcTypography variant="body1" css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>
            fsdfasfadsfadsfj might contain components or modules that are Open Source or commercial
            software programs.
          </OwcTypography>
        </div>

        <div css={dialogStatementStyles} style={{ gridRow: 1 }}>
          <OwcTypography variant="subtitle2" css={{ gridColumn: 1 }}>
            For use statement
          </OwcTypography>
          <OwcTypography variant="body1" css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>
            fhjkashfjkhsakfj is a software platform intended to provide bi-directional, standardized
            and secure data integration and communication between safdfasf data sources fsfsafsdaf
            and to cloud-based products.
            <br />
            <br />
            fhjkashfjkhsakfj is not intended as a primary diagnostic tool by fsdfasfda or to be used
            as a substitute for professional fsdfasdsf advice. It is not intended to interpret or
            analyze or other device data, results, or findings. It is not a substitute for a data
            sources.
          </OwcTypography>
        </div>

        <div css={{ gridArea: 'regulations', display: 'grid' }}>
          <div css={{ gridColumn: 1 }}>3A</div>
          <div css={{ gridColumn: 2 }}>3B</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Problem:**

In my first Grid column, my second row should be right underneath the first row `Software Version` but it is aligning of the height of the second columns row height.

Comment: Software and Statement are both `gridRow: 1`, so they're treated as being in the same row.